# Exception when using collect on Spark Dataframe that is a union of Selects of another dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

def yearFrame(x: String) : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = {
    val csv0 = sc.textFile("Data/Casos_Notificados_Dengue_01_"+x+".csv")

    val csv = sc.textFile("Data/*"+x+".csv")

    val rdd = csv.mapPartitionsWithIndex(
        ((i,iterator) => if (i == 0 && iterator.hasNext){
          iterator.next
          iterator.next
          iterator
        }else iterator), true)

    var schemaArray = csv0.collect()(1).split(",")
    schemaArray(0) = "NU_NOTIF" //Corrigindo mudança de header de 2011 para 2012
    val schema =
      StructType(
        schemaArray.map(fieldName => 
        if(fieldName == "NU_NOTIF") StructField(fieldName, StringType, false))
        else StructField(fieldName, StringType, true))      
        )

    val rowRDD = rdd.map(_.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)")).map(p => Row.fromSeq(p))

    // Apply the schema to the RDD.
    val schemaRDD = sqlContext.applySchema(rowRDD, schema)

    // Register the SchemaRDD as a table.
    schemaRDD.registerTempTable("casos")

    // SQL statements can be run by using the sql methods provided by sqlContext.
    val r = sqlContext.sql("SELECT NU_NOTIF,NU_ANO,Long_WGS84,Lat_WGS84 FROM casos")
    return r
}

val years = List("2010","2011","2012","2013","2014")
val allTables = years.map(x => yearFrame(x))
val finalTables = allTables.reduce(_.unionAll(_))
```

This executes without a problem, so let's say i want now to get all rows with NU_ANO = 2014:

```
scala> val a = finalTables.filter("NU_ANO = 2014")
a: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [NU_NOTIF: string, NU_ANO: string, Long_WGS84: string, Lat_WGS84: string]

scala> a.first
15/05/28 11:42:59 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 91.0 (TID 287)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
15/05/28 11:42:59 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 91.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
15/05/28 11:42:59 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 91.0 (TID 288)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
15/05/28 11:42:59 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 3.0 in stage 91.0 (TID 290)
org.apache.spark.TaskKilledException
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:194)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 91.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 91.0 (TID 287, localhost): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1204)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1193)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1192)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1192)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:245)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1393)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1354)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)

scala> a.schema
res116: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(NU_NOTIF,StringType,true), StructField(NU_ANO,StringType,true), StructField(Long_WGS84,StringType,true), StructField(Lat_WGS84,StringType,true))

scala> a.count
15/05/28 11:43:13 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 92.0 (TID 293)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
15/05/28 11:43:13 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 1 in stage 92.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
15/05/28 11:43:13 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 2.0 in stage 92.0 (TID 294)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
15/05/28 11:43:13 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 3.0 in stage 92.0 (TID 295)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
15/05/28 11:43:13 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 4.0 in stage 92.0 (TID 296)
org.apache.spark.TaskKilledException
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:194)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 92.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 92.0 (TID 293, localhost): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1204)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1193)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1192)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1192)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:245)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1393)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1354)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

So, it didn't work, let's try collecting the data and iterating in a map:

```
scala> finalTable
finalTable   finalTables

scala> finalTables.count
res118: Long = 226570                                                           

scala> finalTables.collect()
15/05/28 11:45:59 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 96.0 (TID 351)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
15/05/28 11:45:59 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 1 in stage 96.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 96.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 96.0 (TID 351, localhost): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1204)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1193)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1192)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1192)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:245)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1393)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1354)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

Now, i do know i did something wrong and in case someone wonders, the error is the same if i try to pick only "r" or any other Dataframe, with the exception of "SchemaRDD". Anyone encountered a similar problem and/or has a suggestion?

I am using Spark 1.3.1 by the way.

Comment: Because of lazy evaluation, you probably have issues the exception probably doesn't get exposed until you do `a.first`.

Comment: It was a problem with the files themselves (first line is a bogus ç character on all files) i will post the code that worked if doing everything on scala but it's probably better if i could pre-process all files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that doing a textFile of a group of files was what i was doing wrong, not because of any problem with scala or spark but rather the files starting with only a bogus "ç" character on the first line. I will post bellow the modified code that worked.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

def g(x: String, y:String = "2010") : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = {
    val csv = sc.textFile("Data/Casos_Notificados_Dengue_"+x+"_"+y+".csv")
    val rdd = csv.mapPartitionsWithIndex(
        ((i,iterator) => if (i == 0 && iterator.hasNext){
          iterator.next
          iterator.next
          iterator
        }else iterator), true)
    var schemaArray = csv.collect()(1).split(",")
    schemaArray(0) = "NU_NOTIF" //Corrigindo mudança de header de 2011 para 2012
    val schema =
      StructType(
        schemaArray.map(fieldName => 
        if(fieldName == "NU_NOTIF") StructField(fieldName, StringType, false)
        else StructField(fieldName, StringType, true)))
    val rowRDD = rdd.map(_.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)")).map(p => Row.fromSeq(p))
    val schemaRDD = sqlContext.applySchema(rowRDD, schema)
    schemaRDD.registerTempTable("casos")
    val r = sqlContext.sql("SELECT NU_NOTIF,NU_ANO,Long_WGS84,Lat_WGS84 FROM casos")
    return r
}

val months = List[String]("01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12")
val years = List(List("2010",months),List("2011",months),List("2012",months),List("2013",months),List("2014",List("01","02","03")))
val allTables = years.map(x => (x(1).asInstanceOf[List[String]]).map(y => g(y.toString(),x(0).toString())).reduce(_.unionAll(_)))
val finalTable = allTables.reduce(_.unionAll(_))
```

Although it's not the best way this is enough for the purpose of a prototype, the best would be for the files to be pre-processed as they are downloaded.